# Coverting R output table to editable Word document

Tags: r, cpu-word, summary, gtsummary

Does anyone know how to covert an R table output to an editable word document? For reference I tried the following code for my table, but seem to be getting an XML error. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Code]

Answer (score 0):

The best way and simpler one I found is to:

**1-** save your data frame as **.CSV** file using **R code** but you shouldn't save the indexes also like this: 
`write.csv(table1, "table1.csv", row.names= F)`
**2-** Open the .CSV file using **Microsoft word** by **right-click** and open with then choose word app
**3-** Click `ctrl + a` then click on `Table>Convert>Conevrt text to table` you'll find this dialoge box:[image: convert text to table dialouge box]

click OK.

*Some notes*: after doing this you can save the word file as XML file and you can design it as you want
*Scources*: https://www.rforecology.com/post/exporting-tables-from-r-to-microsoft-word/

Comment: Hi, so I am trying this and when I run the first line you suggested, I get the error "Error in write.table(table1, "table1.csv", row.names = F, col.names = TRUE,  : unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'

Answer (score 0):

You tagged the gtsummary package, so I presume you're using it to create the table?

There are various ways to convert a gtsummary table to Word output. Review this vignette for more details. https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html

```
library(gtsummary)

trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt)  %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  gt::gtsave(filename = "my_table.docx")
```

Comment: Yes that's right. When I try this though and try to open the word doc, I am getting an error in the word doc that it can't open the contents, so not sure how to ensure it opens in word

Comment: I'll look at the link you sent